# detect for size change VB.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, size

I've been looking around but cant find anything simular in VB.net.

I want to run the following code if the form size changes

```
        'Sets the TabControll size
    Me.TabControl1.Size = New Size(Me.ClientRectangle.Width, 21)
```

Is it possible to check \ detect form size changes made by the user?

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on the `Resize Event` of the form

```
 Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    'Sets the TabControll size
    Me.TabControl1.Size = New Size(Me.ClientRectangle.Width, 21)
 End Sub
```

It is triggered when the form is maximised or its size is changed in any other way (from the code or "manually" by the user).